# No me funciona Download Manager en android 8,9

Tags: java, android, android-studio, programación-móvil

Tengo la siguiente clase dentro de mi proyecto de ejemplo
DownloadDemo

```
public class DownloadDemo extends Activity {
    private DownloadManager mgr=null;
    private long lastDownload=-1L;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_download_demo);
        Toast.makeText(DownloadDemo.this, "Activity 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mgr=(DownloadManager)getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        registerReceiver(onComplete,
                new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
        registerReceiver(onNotificationClick,
                new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_CLICKED));
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(onComplete);
        unregisterReceiver(onNotificationClick);
    }
    public void startDownload(View v) {
        Uri uri=Uri.parse("https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/38/38002.png");
        Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
                .mkdirs();lastDownload= mgr.enqueue(new DownloadManager.Request(uri)
                      .setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI |
                                DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
                        .setAllowedOverRoaming(false)
                        .setTitle("Demo")
                        .setDescription("Something useful. No, really.")
                        .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,
                                "test.mp4"));
        v.setEnabled(false);
        findViewById(R.id.query).setEnabled(true);
    }
    public void queryStatus(View v) {
        Cursor c=mgr.query(new DownloadManager.Query().setFilterById(lastDownload));

        if (c==null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Download not found!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else {
            c.moveToFirst();
            Log.d(getClass().getName(), "COLUMN_ID: "+                    c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_ID)));
            Log.d(getClass().getName(), "COLUMN_BYTES_DOWNLOADED_SO_FAR: "+                   c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_BYTES_DOWNLOADED_SO_FAR)));
            Log.d(getClass().getName(), "COLUMN_LAST_MODIFIED_TIMESTAMP: "+                   c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LAST_MODIFIED_TIMESTAMP)));
            Log.d(getClass().getName(), "COLUMN_LOCAL_URI: "+                   c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI)));
            Log.d(getClass().getName(), "COLUMN_STATUS: "+
                    c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS)));
            Log.d(getClass().getName(), "COLUMN_REASON: "+
                    c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_REASON)));
            Toast.makeText(this, statusMessage(c), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    public void viewLog(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(DownloadManager.ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS));
    }
    private String statusMessage(Cursor c) {
        String msg="???";
        switch(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS))) {
            case DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED:
                msg="Download failed!";
                break;
            case DownloadManager.STATUS_PAUSED:
                msg="Download paused!";
                break;
            case DownloadManager.STATUS_PENDING:
                msg="Download pending!";
                break;
            case DownloadManager.STATUS_RUNNING:
                msg="Download in progress!";
                break;
            case DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL:
                msg="Download complete!";
                break;
            default:
                msg="Download is nowhere in sight";
                break;
        }
        return(msg);
    }
    BroadcastReceiver onComplete=new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
            findViewById(R.id.start).setEnabled(true);
        }
    };
    BroadcastReceiver onNotificationClick=new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
            Toast.makeText(ctxt, "Ummmm...hi!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };
}
```

La llamo en mi MainActivity

Intent intent = new Intent(this, DownloadDemo.class);
        startActivity(intent);

Y tengo agregado los permisos en el manifiesto

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Pero al momento de ejecutar la aplicación en el emulador no se descarga pero al revisar la carpeta de descargas me doy cuenta que la imagen se queda encolada y después intenta descargar de nuevo y pasa exactamente lo mismo , la probé en un dispositivo físico (TV-BOX) y me descarga si tengo activado el wifi , pero si activo datos o conecto un cable de ethernet tampoco me descarga y en la carpeta de descargas no se ve ningún archivo encolado.
Me falta algún permiso por agregar o que soluciones me darían?
Alguien me podría ayudar explicando que mismo es lo que pasa o que deberia modificar?

Comment: No estas requiriendo  el permiso WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE manualmente?

Comment: Si al iniciar la aplicación pido los permisos de escritura y lectura